# What could be the problem with this TLS 1.2 Client Finished Message approach?

Tags: tls

Can someone make sure I'm creating my Client finished message properly as I've been working at this for days and keep getting a Bad record MAC error and I have no idea what I'm doing wrong.

1. First step is creating the 12 bytes of verify data. This is created using the PRF with the master secret, the label "client finished", and the sha256 digest of all the previous handshake messages. (The cipher suite is TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256).
2. The 12 bytes are then placed in the finished handshake record with a handshake type field and 3byte length field.
3. These 16 bytes are then passed through the sha256 HMAC, which has as input:

   - the sequence number (for a finished message this is number 3 as the previous 3  messages were the client hello, the client key exchange, and the change cipher spec)
   - the type - 0x14
   - the version - 0x0303
   - the length -16
   - the 16 bytes of 'plain text data'
4. This produces 32 bytes of hash which are tagged onto the 16 bytes of data, creating 48 bytes before padding (49 if you include the padding length field). And so we add 15 bytes of padding with value 0x0F. This takes the total length to 64 bytes (a multiple of the block size 16).
5. The 64 bytes are then encrypted with using the IV and the client write key.
6. The 64 bytes, preceded by the 16 byte IV are sent to the server - 80 bytes in total.

What am I doing wrong?

#### EDIT

Thanks for the pointers guys! Don't know why I hadn't thought of debugging another implementation to find where I was going wrong. Turns out the library I was using for calculating my SHA256 HMAC (I was using Nettle) was a bit buggy. I imported another library and managed to get it all working!

Comment: Take another implementation of TLS, configure the same cipher suite, use identical keys and randoms on both sides, print out all intermediate values and compare. Just debugging by describing the protocol to us is unlikely to help.

Comment: possibly step 5: "the 64 bytes are then encrypted with using the IV and the client write key". You don't mention computing the GCM tag or the HMAC tag required for this record-layer encryption. This would explain the "bad record MAC" answer.

Comment: @SEJPM the identified suite uses HMAC which OP described *almost* correctly in steps 3 and 4.

Comment: Can anyone answer to the same problem here : https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/100374/tls-1-2-client-finish-message?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 3):

The `sequence_number` resets at CCS, so for `Finished` it's zero (for 8 bytes). Also record type for handshake is 0x16, 
and to be clear the record length is 2 bytes, in this case 00 10, and "the IV" should be random for each record.
As a mnemonic, the RHUL group's [Lucky Thirteen attack](http://www.isg.rhul.ac.uk/tls/Lucky13.html) uses the fact that the HMAC pseudoheader is 13 bytes.

That said I agree with [@Maarten's comment](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/28948/tls1-2-client-finished-message?rq=1#comment66642_28948): debug against another implementation. Especially an open source one like OpenSSL/LibreSSL/BoringSSL or GnuTLS or Java.

Answer (score 1):

First, check all the algorithms that you are using against official test vectors. This solves most of the problems, including the problem with the TLS 1.2 Client Finished Message you are describing. The problem in your case is not the approach, but the actual data being calculated in a chain of calculations. To figure out the exact step where it calculated wrong, compare test vectors and intermediate values (premaster secret, etc.) against other implementation of TLS, like OpenSSL.

In addition to the answer by dave_thompson_085, here is a practical advice on how to debug OpenSSL.

OpenSSL already implements a mechanism that allows you to trace various TLS internal values like Premaster Secret, Client Random, Server Random, Master Secret, Mac Key, Encryption Key, etc., by displaying these values to screen.

By default, the OpenSSL library is built with tracing disabled. To use the tracing functionality, it is therefore necessary to configure and build OpenSSL with the 'enable-trace' option. There is another build option, 'enable-ssl-trace', which adds "-trace" command line parameter for "openssl s_client" and "openssl s_server", but this option is not very useful when you are writing your own TLS implementation, because it only displays additional data for "s_client" and "s_server" rather than TLS internal values like key blocks.

When building OpenSSL, add the "enable-trace" parameter to "Configure". For example, for 64-bit Windows, call:

```
perl Configure enable-trace enable-ssl-trace VC-WIN64A
nmake
```

Then, the "openssl.exe" will read trace options from the `OPENSSL_TRACE` environment variable. This variable accepts the coma-separated list of trace categories.

```
ALL
TRACE
INIT
TLS
TLS_CIPHER
CONF
ENGINE_TABLE
ENGINE_REF_COUNT
PKCS5V2
PKCS12_KEYGEN
PKCS12_DECRYPT
X509V3_POLICY
BN_CTX
STORE
```

To trace TLS internal values, you just need to specify the `TLS` category to `OPENSSL_TRACE`. For example:

```
set OPENSSL_TRACE=TLS
openssl.exe s_server
```

It will start accepting TLS connections on port 4433. Connect to it with your client and you will see on your console trace data like this:

```
TRACE[28:25:00:00]:TLS: Premaster Secret:
TRACE[28:25:00:00]:TLS:     0000 - 00 86 80 fa 69 b4 42 1d-e6 4b 20 b0 ca 42 6a 38   ....i.B..K ..Bj8
TRACE[28:25:00:00]:TLS:     0010 - f9 48 38 5b a1 1b e2 8e-6a 8f 4e 23 28 4b 9f 79   .H8[....j.N#(K.y
TRACE[28:25:00:00]:TLS:     0020 - ac 74 7d c3 4c 9d ba 0f-25 f2 97 89 3c ae 55 48   .t}.L...%...<.UH
TRACE[28:25:00:00]:TLS:     0030 - 92 df 77 4a 20 4e d8 a3-85 64 1e 35 55 72 c4 b5   ..wJ N...d.5Ur..
TRACE[28:25:00:00]:TLS:     0040 - a3 52                                             .R
TRACE[28:25:00:00]:TLS: Client Random:
TRACE[28:25:00:00]:TLS:     0000 - 5e 5c 2f 41 f4 8d 66 46-d7 fa 2d d2 16 2d 0d 31   ^\/A..fF..-..-.1
TRACE[28:25:00:00]:TLS:     0010 - de f5 5a 53 91 86 48 a7-ec af 9d 0c 16 03 d2 ec   ..ZS..H.........
TRACE[28:25:00:00]:TLS: Server Random:
TRACE[28:25:00:00]:TLS:     0000 - 78 9c 50 33 93 38 70 f7-77 d6 43 5f be 20 4d 08   x.P3.8p.w.C_. M.
TRACE[28:25:00:00]:TLS:     0010 - c6 52 67 0d 8c 89 b0 0c-44 4f 57 4e 47 52 44 01   .Rg.....DOWNGRD.
TRACE[28:25:00:00]:TLS: Master Secret:
TRACE[28:25:00:00]:TLS:     0000 - 1f 5d bd 13 92 b9 34 ef-24 dc ee 2f 60 76 82 16   .]....4.$../`v..
TRACE[28:25:00:00]:TLS:     0010 - 0c a7 db 51 2a 69 46 23-8d 64 75 72 71 24 81 d1   ...Q*iF#.durq$..
TRACE[28:25:00:00]:TLS:     0020 - 52 3c 1a 68 9a d8 4a 00-38 5d 95 84 05 14 4f 69   R<.h..J.8]....Oi
TRACE[28:25:00:00]:TLS: dec 1
TRACE[28:25:00:00]:TLS:     0000 - 01                                                .
TRACE[28:25:00:00]:TLS: client random
TRACE[28:25:00:00]:TLS:     0000 - 5e 5c 2f 41 f4 8d 66 46-d7 fa 2d d2 16 2d 0d 31   ^\/A..fF..-..-.1
TRACE[28:25:00:00]:TLS:     0010 - de f5 5a 53 91 86 48 a7-ec af 9d 0c 16 03 d2 ec   ..ZS..H.........
TRACE[28:25:00:00]:TLS: server random
TRACE[28:25:00:00]:TLS:     0000 - 78 9c 50 33 93 38 70 f7-77 d6 43 5f be 20 4d 08   x.P3.8p.w.C_. M.
TRACE[28:25:00:00]:TLS:     0010 - c6 52 67 0d 8c 89 b0 0c-44 4f 57 4e 47 52 44 01   .Rg.....DOWNGRD.
TRACE[28:25:00:00]:TLS: master key
TRACE[28:25:00:00]:TLS:     0000 - 1f 5d bd 13 92 b9 34 ef-24 dc ee 2f 60 76 82 16   .]....4.$../`v..
TRACE[28:25:00:00]:TLS:     0010 - 0c a7 db 51 2a 69 46 23-8d 64 75 72 71 24 81 d1   ...Q*iF#.durq$..
TRACE[28:25:00:00]:TLS:     0020 - 52 3c 1a 68 9a d8 4a 00-38 5d 95 84 05 14 4f 69   R<.h..J.8]....Oi
TRACE[28:25:00:00]:TLS: key block
TRACE[28:25:00:00]:TLS:     0000 - a0 0e 22 a5 56 fc 7a 20-88 0d 50 61 24 60 73 27   ..".V.z ..Pa$`s'
TRACE[28:25:00:00]:TLS:     0010 - 99 cb 03 48 db 27 12 80-7d d9 e6 bc 98 a9 90 e1   ...H.'..}.......
TRACE[28:25:00:00]:TLS:     0020 - 12 72 4d 76 04 c1 b6 d4-5b a8 98 e7 12 de 82 43   .rMv....[......C
TRACE[28:25:00:00]:TLS:     0030 - e7 21 bd 6c ba cc 65 1a-03 28 9a ac d4 00 0d 50   .!.l..e..(.....P
TRACE[28:25:00:00]:TLS:     0040 - 75 b3 bb 7f 6f f1 f7 28-5d cd cd d8 2f 8e 1b 21   u...o..(].../..!
TRACE[28:25:00:00]:TLS:     0050 - 8a fd bd 6b b6 3a dc 85-                          ...k.:..
TRACE[28:25:00:00]:TLS: which = 0021, mac key:
TRACE[28:25:00:00]:TLS: which = 0021, key:
TRACE[28:25:00:00]:TLS:     0000 - a0 0e 22 a5 56 fc 7a 20-88 0d 50 61 24 60 73 27   ..".V.z ..Pa$`s'
TRACE[28:25:00:00]:TLS:     0010 - 99 cb 03 48 db 27 12 80-7d d9 e6 bc 98 a9 90 e1   ...H.'..}.......
TRACE[28:25:00:00]:TLS: iv:
TRACE[28:25:00:00]:TLS:     0000 - 75 b3 bb 7f                                       u...
TRACE[28:25:00:00]:TLS: dec 40
TRACE[28:25:00:00]:TLS:     0000 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00-00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   ................
TRACE[28:25:00:00]:TLS:     0010 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00-5d b0 62 5e 16 39 df 82   ........].b^.9..
TRACE[28:25:00:00]:TLS:     0020 - 02 9d d2 3d 19 7d 07 8f-                          ...=.}..
```

Comment: Im working on cipher suite : ECDHE_ECDSA_AES_128_CBC_SHA256. I would like to ask for a clarification on the step 3. in your post. When you said "the 16 bytes of 'plain text data'". Are these bytes actually contains : (A) 1 byte of finish_message = 0x14 ? or (B) 3 bytes of verify_data_length = 12 ? or (C) 12 bytes of verify_data ?

Comment: @AiinZul - it was not me who wrote the post (with 3 steps) but "chadianscot". My reply was that we can use OpenSSL trace option to see actual contents of the packets, including the of the plaintext data of the Client Finished Message. In TLS v1.0 and later, the data contain the following: 1 byte tag (finish_message) + 3 bytes length + 12 bytes generated by the PRF.