# TLS 1.2 client finish message

Tags: aes, tls, sha-256

Im working on TLS1.2 on cipher suite ECDHE_ECDSA_AES_128_CBC_SHA256. Im currently at the stage of client encrypted message where I always got error on wireshark from the server saying that Fatal, Description : Handshake Failure. So from what I have done my research, the contain for this client finish message suppose to go through these steps :

1. 1 byte of handshake type : finish = 0x14
2. 3 bytes of data_verify_length = 12
3. 12 bytes of verify_data
4. These 16 bytes from steps 1),2) and 3) are passed through hmac_sha256 and gives and produces 32 hash bytes. Can someone confirm me the inputs?
   5)The 32 bytes are preceded with 16 bytes from steps 1),2) and 3) and gives a total of 48 bytes before padding
5. We added 1 byte length of padding and 15 bytes of padding of 0x0F and gives a total of 64 bytes
6. The 64 bytes are then encrypted with client IV and client encryption key
7. The 64 bytes are preceded with 16 bytes of IV before sending to server

Could someone verify all the steps and corrected me if I'm wrong because I kept getting handshake failure at this point.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

As stated in [this 2015 question plus my answer](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/28948/what-could-be-the-problem-with-this-tls-1-2-client-finished-message-approach) which you apparently didn't read even while commenting on the other answer, TLS <=1.2 HMAC is calculated over:

- the *record* seqnum, type, version, and length: hex 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 16 03 03 00 10
- plus the Finished *message* which you correctly have as 1 byte type = 14, 3 bytes length = 00 00 0C, and 12 bytes 'verify_data'

using the client MAC key (from the key derivation process).

You have the subsequent part correct: you CBC-encrypt the record body (which is exactly the handshake message) plus HMAC plus padding (16 times 0F), and prepend the 16-byte IV used (which should be unpredictable, normally random). And prepend to *that* the record header of type = 16, version = 03 03, length = 00 50.

Note that in addition to the record being formatted, HMACed, and encrypted correctly, the verify_data *in* the message must be correct, and IME most people have more trouble getting that right than the record processing.

Reference: [RFC5246 6.2.3.1](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc5246#section-6.2.3.1) (and 6.2.3.2 for CBC encryption)

Comment: Does the total number of input bytes for hmac is 29 bytes according to your post : hex 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 16 03 03 00 10 + 16 bytes (1 byte type + 3 bytes length + 12bytes verify data) ?

Comment: I have corrected my input hmac accroding to your post. But I still have handshake failure problem.

Well let's start from how I did to produce the verify_data :

1) hash of all previous handshake message : SHA256(all_handshake_messages)

2)Then I did prf(maseter_secret, "client_finished", SHA256(all_handshake_messages))

    These produces 12 bytes of verify_data

Then I concatenate the data in step 3) with the data in step 1) and 2) in my very first post I did rest of the steps. What could have cause the Handshake failure ?